# How can I keep 2 blankets together on a bed?

Tags: temperature

I try to use two blankets in the winter when it gets cold, but tossing and turning separates them. In the morning, I'll often wake up with one at the foot of the bed.

Is there any trick to keeping the 2 blankets together despite my tossing and turning? Having different sized blankets with larger one on bottom? Folding them somehow? Burning an effigy in the room? Thoughts?

The blankets don't have to be made of a specific material, as I'll gladly try different ones to get this to work.

Comment: Of what fabric are the blankets made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was in the Marines (what seems like forever and a day ago) I used to hook bungee cords at both bottom corners (which were folded in the hospital corner method) connecting under the mattress pulling the sheets and blankets tight and  one on only one side of top corners under the mattress. So three corners were completely secure and tight so all I had to worry about in the morning was flipping the one unsecured corner down. This does take a little getting used to though sometimes it would feel too tight, but they always stayed in place.

Comment: the fact that I still get new and creative answers to this question is pretty funny - I especially like yours. This is very creative and I could totally see this as a solution. Given it's a queen bed - this could actually work super well without being too tight because the blanket is larger than the one on the cot you're probably remembering.

Comment: Of all the solutions here, yours is the only one which will genuinely solve the problem. Even safety pins or stitching would just result in the 2 blankets jumbling apart in various places as well as being a destructive solution. Kudos to you for a simple solution I never would have thought of!

Answer (score 7):

I have found that if you have two types of blankets, placing the heavier on on top seems to help with the shifting.

Comment: oops I think I accidentally accepted your answer? Didn't mean to. Doesn't actually solve the problem (tried it).

Answer (score 2):

To take a different direction than what's already been suggested. I would look less into the blankets moving and more into *you* moving.

The less you move in your sleep, the less likely you are to displace the blankets. If you do displace the blankets then, it's going to be because you were getting too warm and threw them off; there's nothing to fix that except fixing the temperatures in the room.

Start training your body to move as little as possible. The easiest way to do this is by sleeping on a couch for a while. Unless you have a behemoth couch, there's not going to be enough room for you to toss about like if you were on a bed.

Another way to train your body to lie still, is to place two objects on either side of you in the bed. Two pillows usually work. When you start to roll in your sleep, you'll subconsciously recognize that there are the objects in your way, and keep from moving about so much.

Be warned though, that once you've done this, you can get stuck with it being difficult to sleep when you're not in a specific position that you've trained yourself to sleep.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any trick to keeping the 2 blankets together despite my tossing and turning?

I've had the same problem.

One way to do this is to find longer blankets and tuck them into your bed or under your mattress. If you can tuck them both into the foot *and* side of your bed, it will work pretty well. This might be less feasible if you are not alone in bed.

Some blanket types naturally stick together, too. Fleece for example will stick together better than a blanket without much friction. Try to layer them in such a way that the "high friction" sides stick together, too, if the top/bottom of the blankets are different.

You can also get larger blankets than your bed. If you have a queen, get a king sized blanket(s). This also helps you be able to tuck them in but will also weigh down the blanket on the sides somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

**Flannel duvet cover with multiple blankets**

In the past, I used a (flannel) duvet cover containing a (down) comforter and one or two (army surplus) wool blankets as upper layers.

As long as you fill it by initially stacking all of the blankets and pushing each set of corners into place as if they were one blanket, you can use a fair number. But they should all be as close to the duvet's dimensions as possible.

Once together, they only need to be handled slightly differently than a single blanket while making the bed. (You should hold two corners and their contents quite firmly as you throw the duvet across the bed.)

Answer (score 1):

Pin them together with safety pins. There isn't really much more to be said, but by laying them out how you like them, you can then pin them together at the corners and they won't be able to separate because they will be physically held together.

Comment: This type of approach has been already suggested by another user.

Comment: But the method was much different. IMO using safety pins is a lot more convenient that sewing things together.

Comment: It's the same principle.

Comment: I would suggest that a lifehack is about the practical application rather than the principle. You can make a fire my rubbing two sticks together or by striking a match. They both rely on the principle of generating heat through friction, but for practical terms they require very different amounts of effort.

Comment: In this case pinning and stitching require the same amount, anyway user deleted his answer

Comment: As I have safety pins at home but probably don't have a needle and thread, and even if I did, it would take me forever to thread the needle, it would take me considerably longer to use that method. It would also take longer to remove stitches to separate the blankets at a later date. Your argument simply fails.

Comment: What if I don't have safety pins cause I don't really have a use for them but happen to be quite proficient at stitching, who's argument fails then? And like I said, the other user has deleted his answer, which was not only more efficient it was also safer, safety pins can come lose and pinch you.

Comment: That demonstrates the point that both are viable solutions depending on the circumstances you find yourself in. Please desist from being unreasonably pedantic.

Comment: Both are viable based on the same principle, and although I have already told you that the other user has already deleted his answer, you keep on ranting on how yours is better.

Comment: I feel that the safety pins are a temporary method, to be used if you want to test out the method or if you want to be able to use the blankets singly as well. Sewing is a longer lasting and basically safer method but you will not do it unless you intend to keep the blankets together.

Comment: Edit your answer to add my 2pence if you'd like... use clothes legs to fasten the sheets and duvet together.

Answer (score 1):

I also hate my feet being squished at the foot of the bed. First I wanted a blanket lift. So I got some schedule 40 pvc, 3/4 inch. I created like a U shape. bottom part under the mattress to be held down and top to lift the blanket over bead leaving lots of room for my feet to be unencumbered.  On the bottom rail coming out from under. you can drill pilot holes for attach how you want eye rings. Space them how you want. this is holding down your blanket. so I think i have about 6...going around the sides. you can do this a few ways. Go to Harbor Freight and get a grommet set to put grommets in your blanket . Tie the ribbon, grow grain between the eye hooks and grommet's. it stays in place. Or, using no grommets, at HF also, grab some large tent clamps. They too will accept your ribbon. Run thru eye hook and clamp the blankets together and tie. I then put my bed spread over the top, you don't see the grommets, the ties, the foot is raised ( like a burn cradle hospitals use). You feet are free and warm. you foot blanks stay in. you are holding the bottoms in side to side. Use more clamps if you need to secure at the top or grommets in each blanket holding it together where ever you want or need to.  I'm just a woman who had a problem with hubbys tall frame cramped in a bed shorter than he was and the blankets in a bunch or kicked off. I saw a problem and figured out how to solve it.  I've also used T's that snap on over the straight pipe. I figured out all my turns etc, got all the elbows I needed. this stays tight I did not need any pvc glue either. That way, if you want your room, bed to look nice, you don't want the raised foot, you can gently slip out the vertical bars and lay the bar down....Michelle

Comment: Can you please edits so there is no wall of text? I have tried but I can not see where you end one sentence and start the new. Some white lines between the bits of text will help as well.

Answer (score 1):

When you own a Queen you can get King blankets. But a King...your stuck.
So I've also bought a matching Twin. Cut it in half. figure out how much extra you want. If you have a side sleeper, that steals blankets. We are not big people but my Donkey is good at being a blanket hog. He wraps himself up like a burrito! 
If you want a really wide blanket you can add half the twin to each side.
Or say add 2 feet to each side. To keep in trimmed, you go under the blanket and stitch the cut end, at the same seam like as the top blankets blanked binder tape.
Best to have stitched the raw end of the blanket turned under or using a blanked or hemming stitch so its a clean edge.
You have no raw edges now, it is clean and looks like it was made than way.

All sides have blanket tape on them. You have a big ass blanket!
Most dry cleaners do sewing.
Or, use Velcro and then you can separate the 3 pieces for easier washing if you have a small washer.

Answer (score 1):

Get sewing clamps, or some small, but strong clamps, and clip them around the edges of the blanket and sheet. It might look a little funny to some, but it works. I use it to attach two blankets to my sheet, and it moves together. Each morning I lift one edge to spread it out and it's all connected. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To keep the two blankets together you can purchase blanket cover in which both blankets fit together. Else you can purchase cloth and get the cover stitched. Get the cover having 3 side zip (it is open from 3 sides (cover) and can be closed by zip or hook). Then you can easily put two blankets in it.

Answer (score 0):

And a really easy lifehack answer... get some large coins 2p's in UK or something that size, large buttons? Place the coin/button under both sheets, then on top sheet, wrap an elastic band around the coin. This fastens the 2 sheets together in a temporary fashion allowing you to separate them if required. You also won't get pinched by any pins or needles if they happen to work loose.

Answer (score 0):

When I find my blankets to the sides of the bed, often one to the left and the others to the right, I add an extra blanket. I tend to move around in bed if I am not warm enough in the night.

It has a disadvantage, I am now using 5 blankets, in a 'not cold' bedroom.

So if you are like me, either add a blanket or wear warmer clothing in bed.

Answer (score -1):

fold the edges of blankets as if in a triangle to encase them. that helps with keeping them together

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little on how this is supposed to work? Maybe add a diagram/drawing or something?